# UIButton title different than expected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     Button.titleLabel.text = [[problemSetting objectAtIndex:currentProblem] getP];
}
```

I'm getting text title of "`UIButton`" In this method.
Each time 1 is added to the `currentProblem`, I want to change the text of the label "`UIButton`"

I've build this app 
When I touch this "`UIButton`", it will change to the text of the initial set in "storyboard" the text.
I do not want to see was set the initial even touch the "`UIButton`" and "Default Text"

When I click the `UIButton`, I want to change the title of the `UIButton` to the text that I have taken out of the `problemSetting` array.

Could anyone please tell me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the declaration of `problemSetting`.

Comment: too difficult to understand the problem. Tell us clearly .

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: what have written here? if you want to change title of Button in run time you can use  [Button setTitle:@"Any String" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this may be helpful for you bcoz i also face same problem some days ago then i used this

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *commentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"YOUR_TITLE"];
 [UIButton setAttributedTitle:commentString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Hello kagmanoj.I have fixed the problem of my.Thank you very much!    btn setTitle:[[problemSetting objectAtIndex:currentProblem] getP]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 2):

First if you want to change title of UIButton object you should use:

```
[btn setTitle:@"YOUR TITLE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To change the title when you change value of currentProblem you can override the currentProblem setter (it needs to be property @property NSInteger currentProblem):

```
-(void)setCurrentProblem:(NSInteger)currentProblem
{
    _currentProblem = currentProblem;
    [btn setTitle:@"YOUR TITLE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

If you want to go back to the default title when the button is pressed add this line to your action method:

```
[btn setTitle:@"DEFAULT VALUE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hello Greg.I have fixed the problem of my.Thank you very much!    btn setTitle:[[problemSetting objectAtIndex:currentProblem] getP]forState:UIControlStateNormal];